# Find a pattern in given string of URLs in Lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

In my Lua code I am receiving lot of URLs in  form of string.

Example :

```
['http://www.abc.com/home/', 'http://www.abc.com/', https://www.xyz.com/v/123443/css/' , http://www.xyz.com/css/' ]
```

I want to fetch those URLs which are like :
`https://www.xyz.com/v/123443/css/`   where  `v` is pre-defined string pattern and `123443` is random version generated to URL.

Please help me to fetch all URLs which are having that pattern into it like :
`"/v/12332323/"`

Comment: Did you search is SO for posts about pattern matching in Lua? There are several with lengthy explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = "https://www.xyz.com/v/123443/css/"    
print(str:match("https?://www%.[^/]+(/v/%d+/)%w+"))
```

Output: `/v/123443/`

This pattern matches strings that starts with `http` or `https`, and then `://`, the website name starting with `www.`, a `/`, the pre-defined string `v` and "random" numbers, followed by `/` and other stuff.

Comment: yes all sites are starting with www and they are ending like  v/21323/css  ,  v/12323/javascript  ,   v/23232323/xml